# Para que funcionan las sentencias #endif #if #ifdef?

Tags: c++

Al momento de crear un proyecto en CodeBlocks siempre aparece en el abajo una sentencia `#endif` ¿Que significa esto? ¿Que función le puedo dar a esto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A eso se les llama [Directivas de pre-procesadores](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/), en este caso directamente serian directivas de inclucion condicional.

Segun la documentacion:

> Estas directivas permiten incluir o descartar parte del código de un
>   programa si se cumple una determinada condición.
>
> `#ifdef` permite compilar una sección de un programa solo si la macro que se especifica como parámetro ha sido definida, sin importar cuál
>   sea su valor.

Por ejemplo digamos que tienes una aplicacion y te gustaria que cuando estes desarrollando, siempre inicie con un usuario determinado. En este caso las estas directivas te pueden ayudar:

```
#define PRUEBA


#ifdef PRUEBA
  // CODIGO PARA CARGAR USUARIO POR DEFECTO
#endif
```

El código dentro de la directiva solo sera compilado si `PRUEBA` esta definida. Así cuando vayas a publica tu aplicación, solo tendieras que eliminar la definicion de `PRUEBA` y el programa seguira su flujo normal.

Answer (score 3):

Tal y como ha comentado [Einer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/120526/2742) las directivas de pre-procesador `#endif`, `#if` y `#ifdef` (y `#ifndef`, `#elif`, `#else` y `#endif` que no habéis mencionado) son directivas de inclusión condicional de código.

Estas directivas no son exclusivas de C++, también son usadas en [c](/questions/tagged/c).

#### Fases de traducción.

El proceso de compilación de código se divide en 9 fases en C++, a grandes rasgos:

1. Se comprueba que todos los caracteres del código son usables.
2. Se unen las líneas separadas por barra descendente (`\`).
3. Se clasifica el contenido del código en comentarios, espacios y directivas de pre-procesador; los comentarios son substituidos por un espacio ().
4. **Se ejecuta el pre-procesador**.
5. Se procesan los literales de cadena de texto (las secuencias de escape se reemplazan por el caracter correspondiente).
6. Se concatenan los literales de texto adyacentes.
7. Se analiza sintáctica y semánticamente el código y se compila.
8. Se examinan las unidades de traducción para listar las instancias de plantillas requeridas en cada una.
9. Se unen las unidades de traducción para generar el programa final.

#### ¿Qué hace la fase 4?

En la fase 4 se ejecuta el pre-procesador, todas las macro `#define` son reemplazadas por el valor definido, el contenido de los archivos incluidos mediante `#include` es copia-pegado en el punto en que aparece la directiva (aplicándoles las fases 1 a 4 recursivamente) y el código que no cumpla con las condiciones de inclusión condicional (`#endif`, `#if`, `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, `#elif`, `#else` y `#endif`) es eliminado.

Supongamos que tenemos estos archivos:

`Objeto.hpp`

```
#ifndef OBJETO_HPP
#define OBJETO_HPP

struct Objeto {
    int a, e, i, o, u;
    const bool debug =
#ifdef _DEBUG
    true;
#else
    false;
#endif
};

#endif
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "Objeto.hpp"
#include "Objeto.hpp"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

El archivo `main.cpp` sufrirá las siguientes transformaciones al ser compilado (en el ejemplo lo compilaremos con `_DEBUG` definido):

1. Resolver inclusiones (`#include "archivo"`).

   ```
   #ifndef OBJETO_HPP
   #define OBJETO_HPP

   struct Objeto {
       int a, e, i, o, u;
       const bool debug =
   #ifdef _DEBUG
       true;
   #else
       false;
   #endif
   };

   #endif
   #ifndef OBJETO_HPP
   #define OBJETO_HPP

   struct Objeto {
       int a, e, i, o, u;
       const bool debug =
   #ifdef _DEBUG
       true;
   #else
       false;
   #endif
   };

   #endif

   int main()
   {
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Eliminar el código no incluido condicionalmente (`#endif`, `#if`, `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, `#elif`, `#else` y `#endif`).

   ```
   #ifndef OBJETO_HPP
   #define OBJETO_HPP

   struct Objeto {
       int a, e, i, o, u;
       const bool debug =
   #ifdef _DEBUG
       true;
   #else

   #endif
   };

   #endif
   #ifndef OBJETO_HPP












   #endif

   int main()
   {
       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Eliminar las directivas de pre-procesador (todo lo que empieza por `#`)

   ```
   struct Objeto {
       int a, e, i, o, u;
       const bool debug =

       true;



   };

















   int main()
   {
       return 0;
   }
   ```

#### El pre-procesador no es el compilador.

El compilador recibirá los archivos de código después de que el pre-procesador los haya digerido, ambas rutinas son independientes y no interactúan. Esto es importante ya que implica que no puedes usar nada del pre-procesador en C++ ni nada de C++ en el preprocesador:

```
#define CONCUPISCENCIA

bool funcion()
{
//      vvvvvvvvvvvvvv <--- No funciona!!
    if (CONCUPISCENCIA)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

//  vvvvvvvvv <--- No funciona
#if funcion()
int main()
#else
int WinMain()
#endif
{
    return 0;
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior `CONCUPISCENCIA` es un símbolo del pre-procesador así que no puede ser usado en un `if` de C++ ya que el lenguaje no sabe de su existencia. Por otro lado la función `bool funcion()` pertenece a C++ por ello el pre-procesador no la puede interpretar para la inclusión condicional.