# error definiciones multiples CPP

Tags: c++

Tengo un objeto global definido en un archivo "objeto.h" de la forma:

```
#ifndef objetoo__h
#define objetoo__h
typedef struct objeto {
  int a;
} objeto;
objeto objetin;
#endif
```

Luego defino una clase en "clase.h" y su implementación en "clase.cpp".
En clase.h procedo de la siguiente forma:

```
#ifndef clase__h
#define clase__h
#include "objeto.h"
extern objeto objetin;
class clase { ...
}
#endif
```

En clase.cpp simplemente pongo en la directivas del preprocesador:

```
#include "clase.h"
```

Es en clase.cpp donde hago uso del objeto global objetin. El problema que tengo es que despues, haciendo uso de un tercer archivo main.cpp en el que incluyo "objeto.h" y "clase.h" y de nuevo declaro extern objetin, el compilador g++ me da error por definiciones multiples de objetin, sin embargo, si en lugar de usar un archivo separado para la implementación de clase.h, pongo las definiciones de los metodos en clase.h, este problema desaparece. ¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: Por favor provee el ejemplo completo, ya que quizas  implementemos lo faltante de forma incorrecta. Tu debes proveer un [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Porque no estás entendiendo cómo funcionan las Unidades de Traducción y las inclusiones, aquí tienes dos hilos que explican cada uno de esos conceptos:

- [Simbolo externo sin resolver ¿Qué he hecho mal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65557/simbolo-externo-sin-resolver-qu%C3%A9-he-hecho-mal) .
- [Para que funcionan las sentencias #endif #if #ifdef?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/120518/para-que-funcionan-las-sentencias-endif-if-ifdef/120901#120901) .

Tras leer esos dos hilos, te será más fácil entender este esquema:
[image]

La condición para que un objeto marcado como `extern` funcione es que puede tener múltiples declaraciones pero sólo una definición. Los archivos de cabecera (`.h` o `.hpp`) no generan Unidad de Traducción (UdT), son copia-pegados directamente sobre un archivo de código (`.cpp`).

Por lo tanto tu definición `objeto objetin;` va a parar tanto a la UdT de `clase.cpp` como a la UdT de `main.cpp`, en esta última no recibes dos definiciones de `objetin` por las guardas de inclusión que añadiste en `objeto.h`, de no haberlas puesto recibirías un `objeto objetin;` desde `objeto.h` y desde `clase.h`.

En el momento de invocar al enlazador, nos encontramos que `objetin` está declarado como `extern` en `clase.h` y definido tanto en `clase.cpp` como en `main.cpp` y el enlazador se queja de definición múltiple.

#### Solución.

> Es en `clase.cpp` donde hago uso del objeto global `objetin`.

Si esto es cierto, mueve la definición `objeto objetin;` de `objeto.h` a `clase.cpp`.

#### En C++ `struct` no forma parte del tipo.

En C++ no es necesario anteponer `struct` antes de los tipos estructura, tu definición de objeto puede quedar así:

```
struct objeto {
  int a;
};
```